# Interchanging order of integration in the Mellin transform

Tags: complex-analysis, dirac-delta, integral-transforms, regularization, mellin-transform

It is possible to understand (perhaps somewhat non-rigorously) the Fourier transform through interchanging order of integration and use of the delta function, like so:
$$\hat{f}(k)\equiv\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx \,f(x)e^{ikx},$$ $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dk}{2\pi} \,\hat{f}(x)e^{-ikx}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dy \,f(y)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dk}{2\pi}e^{-ik(x-y)}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dy \,f(y)\delta(x-y)=f(x)$$
Now I'm curious to what extent such a formal manipulation is valid for a Mellin transform (with contour C chosen appropriately).
$$\hat{f}(z)\equiv\int_{0}^{\infty}dk \,k^{z-1}\,f(k),\qquad f(k)=\int_C\frac{dz}{2\pi i} k^{-z}\hat{f}(z)$$

$$\hat{f}(z)=^? \int_C\frac{dw}{2\pi i} \hat{f}(w)\int_{0}^{\infty}dk \,k^{-w+z-1}$$
The $k$ integral doesn't seem to make much sense since no matter what the exponent is it will diverge at one of the limits of integration. In dimensional regularization in physics, we take these integrals to vanish*, which clearly doesn't make any sense in this situation. So it seems that interchanging the order of integration is nonsense.

But in other situations in physics, interchanging the order of integration with the inverse Mellin transform does seem to make sense. Suppose we are calculating some integral $G(z,m)$
$$G(z,m)\equiv \int_{0}^{\infty}dk \frac{k^{z-1}}{k^2+m^2}f(k) =\int_C\frac{dw}{2\pi i} \hat{f}(w)\int_{0}^{\infty}dk \,\frac{k^{-w+z-1}}{k^2+m^2}$$
Now the $k$ integral can be given a meaning in dimensional regularization, which will involve some Euler gamma functions which introduce some new poles in addition to the poles of $\hat{f}(w)$ that we must take into account when we do the final integral over $C$.

So I am wondering how to make sense of the case involving $\hat{f}(z)$, which is equivalent (after a shift of $z$) to $G(z,0)$ which seems to work for non-zero $m$?

---

*<sub>However, note the paper [Gorishnij and Isaev, Teor. Mat. Fiz.; 62.3 (1985)](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjkjvPm4of2AhUljYkEHSz-CywQFnoECAUQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.osti.gov%2Fbiblio%2F6987671-approach-calculation-many-loop-massless-feynman-integrals&usg=AOvVaw3-d94vPoT3YwbKVgxs-Ffl), which argues it should be understood as a delta function $2\pi i \delta(w-z)$</sub>

Comment: I found a discussion that clarified everything for me in the chapter on the Mellin transform in the `Transforms and Applications Handbook' (ed Poularikas). They discuss the relation to the Fourier transform and Mellin transforms of distributions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mellin and inverse Mellin transforms are defined as follows.

---

$$F(z)=\mathcal{M}_k[f(k)](z)=\int\limits_0^\infty f(k)\,k^{z-1}\,dk\tag{1}$$

$$f(k)=\mathcal{M}_z^{-1}[F(z)](k)=\frac{1}{2\,\pi\,i}\int\limits_{c-i\,\infty}^{c+i\,\infty} F(z)\,k^{-z}\,dz\tag{2}$$

---

Replacing $f(k)$ in formula (1) above using formula (2) above (where $z$ is also replaced by $s$) leads to the following.

$$F(z)=\int\limits_0^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2\,\pi\,i}\int\limits_{c-i\,\infty}^{c+i\,\infty} F(s)\,k^{-s}\,ds\right) k^{z-1}\,dk\tag{3}$$

---

Interchanging the order of integration and rearranging some terms in formula (3) above leads to the following.

$$F(z)=\frac{1}{2\,\pi\,i}\int\limits_{c-i\,\infty}^{c+i\,\infty} F(s)\left( \int_0^{\infty } k^{-s} k^{z-1} \, dk\right) \, ds\tag{4}$$

---

Noting the nested integral in formula (3) above is the Mellin transform $\mathcal{M}_k\left[k^{-s}\right](z)=2\,\pi\,\delta(i\,(z-s))$ (see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=MellinTransform%5Bk%5E%28-s%29%2Ck%2Cz%5D)) leads to the following.

$$F(z)=\frac{1}{2\,\pi\,i}\int\limits_{c-i\,\infty}^{c+i\,\infty} F(s)\,2\,\pi\,\delta(i\,(z-s))\,ds\tag{5}$$

---

The integral in formula (5) above can be evaluated by setting $c=z$ and using the variable substitution $s=z+i\,t$ which leads to $ds=i\,dt$ and $t=-i\,(s-z)$. The lower integration limit $s=z-i\,\infty$ becomes $t=-i\,(z-i\,\infty-z)=-\infty$, the upper integration limit $z+i\,\infty$ becomes $t=-i\,(z+i\,\infty-z)=\infty$, $F(s)$ becomes $F(z+i\,t)$, and $\delta(i\,(z-s))$ becomes $\delta(i\,(z-(z+i\,t)))=\delta(t)$ which leads to the following.

$$F(z)=\frac{1}{2\,\pi\,i}\int\limits_{z-i\,\infty}^{z+i\,\infty} F(s)\,2\,\pi\,\delta(i\,(z-s))\,ds=\frac{1}{2\,\pi\,i}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} F(z+i\,t)\,2\,\pi\,\delta(t)\,i\,dt=F(z)\tag{6}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems to be along the lines I have seen using that paper I cited (but it is nicer to phrase the delta function in terms of a Mellin transform). My question about this approach is why is it valid to freely change the contour of integration like that? The choice of $c$ originally had to do with the function $F(s)$ which has poles which you might cross if you change $c$.

Comment: It seems that the delta function evaluates to zero unless the contour strictly passes through it (see e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2370550), changing the contour a little gives a very different answer,  that is why I'm a little skeptical about this. Actually I saw my colleaque argue something like this, and that is what inspired the question to some extent. There must be something right about this since it is giving the right answer, but it seems like cheating to me. If you have any thoughts on this I would be glad to hear.

Comment: The Dirac delta function $\delta(x)$ is only defined for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and only makes sense when integrated along the real axis which limits the valid contours (i.e. valid values of $c$) for evaluating the inverse Mellin transform integral in formula (5) above. For more insight, please see the answer I posted at https://mathoverflow.net/q/294849 (the last part of which specifically addresses the relevant  inverse Mellin transform). The relationship you quoted is incorrect (note it's missing the $i$ inside the Dirac delta function).

Comment: Mathematica also used to evaluate the Mellin transform of $x^y$ incorrectly, but this was corrected in early 2018 as a result of a problem report I submitted to Wolfram in late 2017.

Comment: I thought you were looking for a way (perhaps somewhat non-rigorous) to understand the Mellin transform case which is what I aimed for in my answer above.